# 2015 Subaru Forester Power Tailgate

Tags: power, tailgate

The power tailgate will open about 1/3 of the way and quits.  I can push it open the rest of the way, but it jerks when it opens; like it's taking steps.  After it's open, it will not close with the remote or button; it will only close manually.

It does this whether I use the remote or the inside button.

Comment: Hard to say based on little information.  I'd be looking at the actuator.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!